# Autograph fails to convert if statements from imported notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In a notebook `FuncDef.ipynb` I have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def myfunc(x):      
    if x < 0:
        x = -x
    return x

x = tf.constant(-1)
print(myfunc(x))
```

If I execute it, it runs as expected and prints `tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)`.

Now I try to execute the same code by importing it in another notebook:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
%cd "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks"

!pip install import-ipynb
import import_ipynb
import FuncDef
```

This fails with the following error:

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

It looks as if Autograph fails to convert the `if` statement when executed from an imported piece of code. Is there a fix for that? Of course there's the trivial solution of getting rid of the `if` statement, but I don't want to do that is it would make my actual code much harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely to be in the `import-ipynb` module.

Proof:

**file x.py**

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def myfunc(x):
    if x < 0:
        x = -x
    return x


x = tf.constant(-1)
print(myfunc(x))
```

**File y.py**

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from x import myfunc

x = tf.constant(-1)
print(myfunc(x))
```

The output of `python y.py` is:

```
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

as expected.

Probably the problem is how import-ipynb handles the decorators? (this is just a guess).

It [looks like](https://github.com/axil/import-ipynb/blob/master/import_ipynb.py#L61) the code execution of the cell is just these two lines

```py
                # transform the input to executable Python
                code = self.shell.input_transformer_manager.transform_cell(cell.source)
                # run the code in themodule
                exec(code, mod.__dict__)
```

but I don't see why this code should fail when there are decorators (but perhaps the tf.function decorator is creating some global object somewhere and this way of loading & executing the code is outside of the design of tf.function?)

If you can try to do not use the notebooks (just export the notebook code in a .py file) you can workardound the issue.

Comment: yeah this looks like the only practical solution, although not exactly what I would have preferred.